# Check for the existence of a string in a list of tuples by specific index

Tags: python, list, tuples

If I have:

```
my_list = [('foo', 'bar'), ('floo', 'blar')]
```

how can I easily test if some string is in the first element in any of those tuples?

something like:

```
if 'foo' in my_list
```

where we are just checking the first element of each tuple in the list?

Comment: By "some string is in the first element", do you mean that "foo" is a substring of the first element or that the first element is equal to "foo"?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check only against the first item in each tuple:

```
if 'foo' in (item[0] for item in my_list)
```

Alternatively:

```
if any('foo' == item[0] for item in my_list)
```

Comment: Using the top options, assume it DOES find it. Is there a way to retrieve the index value in the list where it found it?

Answer (score 3):

You can first extract a list of only the first items and then perform a check:

```
>>> my_list = [('foo', 'bar'), ('floo', 'blar')]
>>> 'foo' in list(zip(*my_list))[0]
True
```

Alternatively:

```
>>> 'foo' in next(zip(*my_list))
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the batteries:

```
import operator

if 'foo' in map(operator.itemgetter(0), my_list):
```

This won't create a copy of your list and should be the fastest.

Comment: I used `timeit` to look at how fast yours is in comparison to mine and mine is about 121ms faster. ;) (0.7894101142883301 vs. 0.9111800193786621) :P http://pastie.org/3397302

Comment: Timing is meaningless for such a small example. `'foo' in (my_list[0][0], my_list[1][0])` is *much* faster. And faster still is `'foo' == my_list[0][0] or 'foo' == my_list[1][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if 'foo' in map(lambda x: x[0], my_list):
    <do something>
```

`map` takes each element in the list, applies a function to it, and returns a list of the results. In this case, the function is a lambda function that just returns the first sub element of the original element.

`((0,1),(3,4))` becomes `(0,3)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = iter(my_list)

result = False

while True:
    try:
        x, y = my_list.next()
        if x == 'foo':
            result = True
            break
    except StopIteration:
        break
```